# Return Multiple Rows from Oracle Query in WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return all of or a set number of the rows in my database however with the query below it only returns the first column of the first row and according the debug, it's getting the data however it just doesn't seem to be storing it correctly. It doesn't seem to be a problem with dr.Read because on my debug stop point, it shows the data returned at that point. Am I displaying the data incorrectly using MessageBox.Show?

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select t2.meternumber, t1.blinkdate, t1.blinkcount from (select * from cecc_processed_blinks where trunc(blinkdate) between to_date('01-may-15', 'dd-mon-yy') and to_date('08-may-15', 'dd-mon-yy')) t1 left join meteraccts t2 on t1.serialnumber = t2.serialnumber order by t1.blinkdate desc";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            //Put it in a message box...
            MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0), "Returned Results");
            conn.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on `OracleDataReader` at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

note that `dr.Read()` only reads a single row of data, you need something like:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    // per row logic
}
```

Additionally within your statement:

```
MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0), "Returned Results");
```

this would only show a `MessageBox` for the *first column* of the row returned from the reader. The "0" is your column index.